# Issue running c++ file -- Input/output error

Tags: c++, linux, macos

I have some C++ code that has been running fine for a long time now. I just upgraded my Mac to macOS Catalina and now about 50% of the time when I compile, it runs fine and 50% of the time when I compile and then run I get

```
sh: ./file: Input/output error
```

I can compile no problem. The issue is on executing the file.

I'm compiling with `g++ -std=c++11 -I ext/ file.cpp -o file -ffast-math -O3 -DEIGEN_STACK_ALLOCATION_LIMIT=0`

I have no idea what's going on or how to fix this. I can run everything else seemingly fine.

**EDIT**

When I run `ls -l` I get

```
-rwxr-xr-x  1 NAME  staff  12872 Feb 27 15:21 ./file
```

And `file ./file` returns

```
./compilation_tests/runnable_c_files/3D_P1_non_zero/1/3D_P1_non_zero2: Mach-O 64-bit executable x86_64
```

The really weird thing is that now when I run the first time I get the same Input/output error. However, no matter what, the second time I run it goes perfectly. Further, if I recompile, it works the first time I run.

BUT...when I put this into a python script (using `os.system` to run shell commands) it never works. I need to compile and run twice from my terminal.

**EDIT #2**

I've run a simple hello world and am encountering the same bug. The code is:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    cout << "Hello world!" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I compile with `g++ -std=c++11 test.cpp -o test -ffast-math -O3 -DEIGEN_STACK_ALLOCATION_LIMIT=0` and permutations thereof (mixing flags etc).

And about 50% of the time I am getting the same error. Is this just a hardware issue?

I have no clue what's going on.

Comment: When you get that error, do `ls -l file` and `file file` (yes, there's a command called `file`).  What does those commands report back? And, is the program long? Can you create a [mcve] of it?

Comment: @TedLyngmo edited with updated info. The file is about 20kb compiled (860 kb as a c file). I don't know if I can reproduce as I think it's something about my machine...Thanks!

Comment: Hmm, that looks good. I would be inclined to say that it's the program itself that prints it but the `sh:` part in `sh: ./file: Input/output error` says otherwise. Tricky. Does it work 50/50 even if you don't recompile?

Comment: Once I recompile it works 100%.

Comment: If you recompile the same code over and over again without changes, do you still get a 50/50 chance that the program will be working?

Comment: No. Once I've gotten it to work no matter how many times I recompile I can't recreate the issue (i.e. it runs perfectly).

Comment: Ah... then your code may be exhibiting undefined behavior. Simply rearranging some declarations etc. looks like it breaks the code but in fact, it's broken all the time and when it's "working", it's just displaying one possible outcome of undefined behavior. Have you tried [`valgrind`](https://valgrind.org/)?

Comment: If you show some parts of your code that you feel a bit unsure about, someone could perhaps point out possible problems. Right now, it's just a guessing game.

Comment: @TedLyngmo -- I've now tried to reproduce the error on a minimal example and am encountering it on a simple hello world case. I've updated the question to reflect.

Comment: That looks ok except that `const`  in `char const *argv[]`. It should be `char *argv[]`. Btw, why define `EIGEN_STACK_ALLOCATION_LIMIT` when you don't include any Eigen headers?

Comment: I'm mostly trying to compile and run code that uses Eigen. However, I wanted to use a minimal example of hello world to see if I could recreate the issue. But I wanted to compile it the same way (i.e. with the same flags) as the program I'm really trying to run.

Comment: I see. I think it's safe to say that defining `EIGEN_STACK_ALLOCATION_LIMIT` will not impact your minimal example though. Does removing the `const` affect it?

Comment: No. Now, I've been getting the error on every run (i.e. without any flags)

Comment: How very odd. And the rest of the programs on the computer works fine? Are you running the program directly from the prompt or have you put it in a script or anything like that? Perhaps the `g++` installation has been corrupted. You could try reinstalling it.

Comment: I've tried both. Both give me issues. I'll try uninstalling and reinstalling g++.

Comment: I'm having the same issue, but it is even simpler than this post. Any program I compile (including the simplest "Hello world" program compiled with `g++ main.cpp`) gives this error the first time it is run. Re-run and it works fine.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to run compiled C++ programs on first execution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63604269/unable-to-run-compiled-c-programs-on-first-execution)

Comment: Do you have Cylance (or other threat detection software) running on your machine?