# Unable to run compiled C++ programs on first execution

Tags: c++, macos-catalina

Ever since upgrading to Mac OS Catalina, any time I compile a C++ program, it does not run the first time. The program compiles as expected and the executable is created and appears normal in all regards. However, when I run the program it immediately prints:

> -bash: ./a.out: Input/output error

Immediately running the program again works exactly as expected. Below is a screenshot of the flow and the simple program used to generate the errors.

```cpp
#include <iostream>

int main ()
{
    std::cout << "test\n";
    return 0;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Don't put a picture of the commands you've used. Copy/paste them into the question instead so that others can copy/paste them too. Have you read [Got “input output error” when execute any commands](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/542554/got-input-output-error-when-execute-any-commands)?

Comment: read this https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/542554/got-input-output-error-when-execute-any-commands

Comment: That question is not applicable here. The problem is not that I cannot run programs from the CLI, but simply C++ that programs I compile. This problem happens, as shown above, only on the first execution of the program. Second, and subsequent, executions work fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After days of digging, I was able to resolve the issue. The problem was that my organization uses Cylance, and advanced threat mitigation tool. After Catalina upgrade, Cylance lost its *Full Disk Access* under the security settings in system preferences. I granted the permissions and was able to get an updated policy that fixed the problem.

I had run `sudo dmesg` and noticed the line:

> hook_thread_userret calledCyProtectDrv.MemDef ERROR

which seemed like a potential issue. I searched for that string and saw that the first result was Cylance related. That is what led me down this very specific path to a solution. I hope this saves someone else a bunch of hours.

Answer (score 0):

Input/output error is probably due to problems in the filesystem. If youre using a outdated version from a long time and dont have required free storage and RAM, this problem can occur.

Try rebooting your computer.
If that doesnt work try reinstalling the OS again if possible.

Comment: I have over 700GB remaining on the filesystem, and as noted, subsequent runs of the program work as desired. I've tried several reboots as well as compiling with a different C++ compiler, with no change in the behavior.